# Multiple controllers or single master controller

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller, controller

**Problem**

> I know this is a bit of a conceptual question, but I am designing a
>   system and I am not sure if I want to use one script as a "Master
>   Controller", that talks to my PHP classes for the business logic, OR
>   if I wanted to create multiple smaller controllers that only focus on
>   certain tasks.

**Example**

> For example, if I wanted to control ALL  the functions of the
>   site(user management, times heets, reporting, and so forth), should I
>   combine all those "getter/setter" functions into one script, or should
>   I break it up into sections (one controller for user management, one
>   for time sheets and so forth). I am using AJAX to call these scripts
>   when needed.

**My Request**

> My thinking is that I should use multiple smaller controllers, that
>   way when multiple users are accessing the site, they are not all
>   trying to execute that same script at the same time. I would expect
>   that if I used one big controller, that it could cause problems with
>   symptoms that would act like a DDOS. However, I am unsure if that
>   would actually happen and wanted to get some opinions/alternatives
>   suggestions.

BTW, this is not a MVC architecture per-say, more of a custom monster I am creating.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For a complex system with multiple Ajax calls, you might want to look at the Flux and React systems developed by Facebook. These are open source and available on GitHub. Facebook developed Flux because they got into difficulties with a complex MVC system.

Comment: Sweet! Ive heard of those names, but haven't done any research on those. Will do . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The *[Single Responibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)* suggests to split you controller. It's a fundamental principle of good object oriented design.

Comment: That makes sense, I am of that thought process as well. It also helps with making code more modular in my opinion. Thanks for the feedback!